# By differentiation or otherwise, prove that $(c(z))^2 +(s(z))^2 = 1$

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, convergence-divergence, power-series

Assume that the two power series $s(z) = \sum a_nz^n$ and $c(z) =\sum b_nz^n$ are convergent for all $z\in \mathbb{C},$ and that they satisfy the relations $s'(z) = c(z), c'(z) =-s(z).$ Deduce the identities
$$ a_n = -a_{n-2}/(n(n-1)) , b_n=-a_{n-2}/(n(n-1))
$$(To me, it looks like there is a typo for $a_n$)
If further $s(0)=0, c(0) =1,$ determine $s(z)$ and $c(z)$ completely. By differentiation or otherwise, prove that $(c(z))^2 +(s(z))^2 = 1$

To me it looks like $s(z) = sin(z)$ and $c(z) = cos(z)$ but I don't know what to do with this information.

Also while taking the derivate of the power series in an attempt to deduce the identities, I have
$(n+1)a_{n+1}=b_n$ and it does not seem like I have the correct identity

Comment: The two assumed relations imply that $s''(z) = c'(z) = -s(z)$ and if you compare the coefficients of $s''(z)$ and $-s(z)$ that is where the first relation involving the sequence $(a_n)$ comes from. The other relation is similar. The idea is definitely that $s$ and $c$ are $\sin$ and $\cos$ but it might help to think that the object of the problem is not to "use" or otherwise exploit this insight, but instead to see how much about $\sin$ and $\cos$ can be derived from only the assumed information (and not, e.g., about pictures of angles).  As the exercise shows, it's basically everything.

Comment: @leslietownes could you explain why I have $s''(z) = -s(z)$ as $\sum_{n=2}n(n-1)a_nz^{n-2} = -\sum_{n=0}a_nz^n$? I dont understand where the shift of indicies will occur.

Comment: Your sum implies that $\sum_{n=0} (n+2)(n+1) a_{n+2} z^n = - \sum_{n=0} a_n z^n$ and hence (equating coefficients) that $(n+2)(n+1) a_{n+2} = -a_n$ for all $n \geq 0$. Putting $m = n+2$ this means (rewriting in terms of $m$) that $m(m-1) a_m = -a_{m-2}$ for all $m$. Whether it's $m$ or $n$ or $s$ or $t$ doesn't matter, only the relation matters. Does this help?

Comment: @leslietownes +1 to each of your comments, whose analysis I hijacked (per OP request) in the just added Addendum to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

hint

if $f'(z) = 0$ for all $z$ then $f(z) = $ a constant .

this means that for all $z, f(z) = f(0).$

let $f(z) = [s(z)]^2 + [c(z)]^2.$

---

**Addendum** 
Per request of OP

> determine $s(z)$ and $c(z)$ completely.

Actually, the necessary analysis has already been provided by the comments of leslie townes.  All I need to do is fill in all of the ground work.

First of all, I completely agree with the response of Hagen von Eitzen, so following
through with the first part of my answer (before the Addendum) is the place to start.

$f'(z) = s(z)s'(z) + c(z)c'(z) = s(z)[c(z)] + c(z)[-s(z)] = 0.$

This establishes that for all $z, f(z) = f(0) = 1,$ which completely resolves
the question in the title of the query.

Next, since $s'(z) = c(z)$ and $c'(z) = -s(z)$, you have that 
$s''(z) = c'(z) = -s(z)$ and that $c''(z) = -s'(z) = -c(z).$ 
Therefore,

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty (n)(n-1)[a_n]z^{(n-2)} = s''(z) = -s(z) =
\sum_{n=0}^\infty -a_nz^n = \sum_{n=2}^\infty -a_{(n-2)}z^{n-2}.$$

As a result, you have that for each $n \in \{2,3,4,\cdots\}$ 
$(n)(n-1)a_n = -a_{(n-2)}.$

By identical analysis, for each $n \in \{2,3,4,\cdots\}$ 
$(n)(n-1)b_n = -b_{(n-2)}.$

All that remains is to compute $a_0, a_1, b_0, b_1.$

Since $a_0 = s(0) = 0$ and $b_0 = c(0) = 1$, 
it is immediate that $a_0 = 0$ and $b_0 = 1.$

Also, remember that for all $z$, you have that $s'(z) = c(z)$ and $c'(z) = -s(z).$ 
Therefore, since $a_1 = s'(0) = c(0) = 1$, and $b_1 = c'(0) = -s(0) = 0$, 
it is immediate that $a_1 = 1$ and $b_1 = 0.$

Comment: could you give me a hint for this part: "If further $s(0)=0, c(0) =1,$ determine $s(z)$ and $c(z)$ completely."

Comment: @pop See the just added Addendum to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

For the desired equation, you do not need the power series, but only the given relations between derivatives, $s'=c$ and $c'=-s$ (plus that the equation holds at $z=0$)

Comment: what about this part:"  "If further $s(0)=0, c(0) =1,$ determine $s(z)$ and $c(z)$ completely."

Comment: the above comment/question of pop is resolved by the just added Addendum to my answer, which refers to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If $s(0) = 0$ and $c(0)=1$ then you can prove your conjecture $s = \sin$ and $c = \cos $ by considering the function
$$
 F(z) = (s(z) - \sin(z))^2 + (c(z) - \cos(z))^2 \, .
$$
We have $F(0) = 0$ and
$$
 F'(z) = 2(s(z) - \sin(z))(c(z)-\cos(z)) + 2(c(z) - \cos(z))(-s(z) + \sin(z)) = 0
$$
so that $F$ is identially zero. This implies $s(x) = \sin(x)$ and $c(x) = \cos(x)$ for all $x \in \Bbb R$, and then  $s = \sin$ and $c = \cos $ because of the identity theorem for holomorphic functions.

Answer (score -1):

**Hint :** Let
$$e : z \mapsto c(z) + i s(z)$$

You get $e'(z)=ie(z)$. Can you proceed further ?