# The solution of this Cauchy–Riemann equations.

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification, cauchy-riemann-equations

・$f(z)=f(x+iy)=e^xu(y)+ie^xv(y)$.

・$f(z)$ is regular.

・$f(x)=e^x.$ (When $y=0$, $f(z)=e^x$.)

Under this condition, determine $u(y), v(y).$

The answer is following.

From Cauchy–Riemann equations, $u(y)=v'(y), u'(y)=-v(y).$

So, $(u(y)^2+v(y)^2)'=2u(y)u'(y)+2v(y)v'(y)=0.$

Thus $u(y)^2+v(y)^2=k$, and from $f(x)=e^x,$ $u(0)=1, v(0)=0.$ Then $k=1.$

Therefore, $u(y)^2+v(y)^2=1$.

The answer is $u(y)=\cos y, v(y)=\sin y.$ ■

But I'm not convinced. This answer says that
$u(y)^2+v(y)^2=1 \Longrightarrow u(y)=\cos y, v(y)=\sin y.$ Aren't there other $u(y),v(y)$ ?  Only $u(y)=\cos y, v(y)=\sin y$  is solution?

Comment: $u(y)=v'(y), u'(y)=-v(y)$ together with $u(0)=1, v(0)=0$ implies $u(y)=\cos y, v(y)=\sin y$, compare   https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4005390/42969.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not convinced either. But the answer is correct. Note that $u''=-v'=-u$ and therefore $u(x)=\alpha\cos(x)+\beta\sin(x)$ for some constants $\alpha$ and $\beta$, and then $v=-u'=\alpha\sin(x)-\beta\cos(x)$. But $\alpha=u(0)=1$ and $\beta=v(0)=0$.